# Driving location behind another vehicle on dusty road

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life

I drive on dusty road daily, and vehicle ahead me throw so much dust in air on driving, and i dont have much option but to drive behind or slight left or right of vehicle. Which place will i gather least dust .

Comment: Maintain a long following distance, much longer than safety would dictate. Do not tailgate.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, leave a large distance to the vehicle in front.  It has the advantages of:

1. letting the dust settle before you reach it
2. letting you see potholes with enough warning, they do not seem to suddenly appear
3. giving you time to stop if the vehicle in front suddenly brakes
4. allowing you to see things ahead, e.g. a traffic queue, if you tailgate, you can't see past the vehicle in front

Comment: It wasn't really a physics question, but hope you find the answer useful for safety reasons.

Comment: i was expecting answer on lines of which direction least dust will come assuming air is stationary , behind vehicle or, on sides, but this also serve purpose.